# jQuery Not Selector and Live Binding

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to bind all of the `a` elements on a page except for those with the title attribute of on. The code below ends up not attaching the click event to any of the `a` elements on the page. If I remove the not it works but of course binds to `a` elements I do not want the code applied to. What am I doing wrong with the [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not/)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('a').not('title=on').live('click', function(event) { ... });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An valid option would be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('a:not([title=on])').live('click', function(event) { ... });
});
```

Here you have another option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('a[title!=on]').live('click', function(event) { ... });
});
```

Comment: Can I ask why the original syntax is not valid?  Going by the documentation it would appear that it should work. Is there something unique to binding that makes the .not() method work differently?

Comment: See my answer for why it's not allowed.

Comment: @kissmyface added an answer which answers your question.

Comment: @jackocnr when you comment on an answer / question and want to let a person know about your reply when they aren't the question owner start the comment w/ an @....

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live):

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send
>   to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called
>   directly after a selector.

I had the same issue, and stumbled across this info here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8378

Comment: That's great. I thought that live would be treated differently because of the way that the events bubble, but this confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a:not[title=on]').live('click', function(event){...});
```